# Loop takes too long to execute (> 500ms)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I trying to edit variable using percentage profitable of strategy in while loop but I getting errro "Loop takes too long to execute (> 500ms)"
"Loop takes too long to execute (> 500ms)"
"Loop takes too long to execute (> 500ms)"

```
varip float percent_profitable = na
GetWinRate(includeEvens = false) =>
    winTradeCount = strategy.wintrades + 
         (includeEvens ? strategy.eventrades : 0)
    (winTradeCount / strategy.closedtrades) * 100
percent_profitable := GetWinRate()
while percent_profitable < 90
    wvalue   := wvalue + 1
```

Comment: I don't know anything about pine but that looks like an infinite loop to me.